How can I solve the problem of extending two rasters?
When I execute this code:
# Calculate VHI for i-month [VHI=(0.5*VCI + 0.5*TCI)]
VHI_12_2021 <- ((0.5*VCI_12_2021 + 0.5*TCI_12_2021))

I get this error:

Error in compareRaster(e1, e2, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, crs = TRUE,  :
different crs

Data summary:
VCI_12_2021
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 753, 2081, 1566993  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 925.5352, 925.5352  (x, y)
extent     : 2123741, 4049780, 3962969, 4659897  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : MODIS13A3_NDVI 
values     : 9.934107e-09, 1  (min, max)

TCI_12_2021
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 138, 312, 43056  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 5551.877, 5551.877  (x, y)
extent     : -163296.7, 1568889, 3964232, 4730391  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=36 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : LST_MOD11B3 
values     : 6.256006e-07, 1.000001  (min, max)


You need to align the coordinate reference systems (crs) of your RasterLayer objects. Check out ?raster::projectRaster(). In addition, eventually consider switching to {terra}.

+1 to the comment from @dimfalk regarding migrating to the terra package. raster was deprecated last year, along with a few associated packages. Unless you are depending on some raster functions that have yet to be migrated to terra, updating is better option.
